# How to find length of longest sorted subsequence

Tags: java

Given a sequence of integer of length and prints the length of the longest sorted subsequence. If there is more than one subsequence of equal maximum length, the subsequence that appears first (the one with the smallest index) is to be used for the output

For the sequence: 8 2 3 4 5 6 0 10 26 24. The max length is 5. Here is the code i have so far. THank you guys.
Note: i am not suppose to use array. I have to use Ctrl+Z to display the max sorted subsequence length.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class RepeatingCharacterPositions {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws IOException {
        int counter = 0;
        int inputValue;
        int previousNum = 0;
        int nextNum;
        while ((inputValue = System.in.read()) != -1) {
            nextNum = (int) inputValue;
            if (previousNum < nextNum) {
                counter++;
            } else if (previousNum > nextNum) {
                continue;
            }
            previousNum = nextNum;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of repeating " + counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck with?  What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: Describe the loop invariant.

Comment: I couldnt display the length of the longest subsequence, it keep display 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're missing a few things.

- You need to remember the **highest value your `counter` reached**
- In order to get an `int` from `System.in`, you should use a `Scanner` which provides the method `Scanner#nextInt`
- If two subsequent numbers are the same, I think that they **ARE** ordered. Your test should be `if (previousNum <= nextNum)`
- If a given number is lower than the previous one, you should "reset" `counter` to the value of **1** (because any number IS itself an **ordered sequence** of **length 1**)

For example:

```
public static void main(final String[] s) {
    int counter = 0;
    int highestCount = 0;
    int previousNum = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int latestStartingPosition = 0;
    int startingPosition = 0;

    int inputValue;
    try (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while ((inputValue = sc.nextInt()) != -1) {
            if (previousNum <= inputValue) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > highestCount) {
                    highestCount = counter;
                    startingPosition = latestStartingPosition;
                }
            } else {
                latestStartingPosition = position;
                counter = 1;
            }

            previousNum = inputValue;
            position++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("starting pos: " + startingPosition);
    System.out.println("Number of repeating positions: " + highestCount);
}
```

I hope it helps!

---

**EDIT: Answering additional question asked in comments.**
To get the index of the beginning of the longest ordered sequence, you have to:

- have an `int` to know your current position at any instant
- have a reference to the **last** starting position you've encountered - this value is changed every time you *reset* your primary `counter`.
- when you detect that a sequence is longer than any other you've ever had before, then the *starting position* of THAT sequence should be the final *starting position*: just save that information any time you save the highest value your `counter` has reached.

See updated example in the code above :)

Comment: One more question. I am stuck at display its starting position. Can you help me with that? Thanks in advance

Comment: I wanted to explain how to do it in a single comment... but I guess I should just edit my answer to add this feature :)

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

1. Your continue clause prevents you from setting previousNum = nextNum.
2. You probably need to reset counter when you find a decreasing number. Which means you also probably need to have a second variable that tracks the longest sequence you've found.
3. You're not handling two consecutive equal values, at least not explicitly. You should consider using a >= or  <= in whichever of your tests makes sense.

   ```
       if (previousNum < nextNum)
       {
           counter++;
       }
       else if (previousNum > nextNum)
       {
           if(counter > longestSeq)
           {
               longestSeq = counter;
           }
           counter = 1;
       }

       previousNum = nextNum;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what ccjmne pointed out, you can always use a separate method to do this:

```
public class RepeatingCharacterPositions {
    public static int findLongestSorted(int[] array) {
        int maxCount = 0, count = 0;
        int prev = array[0];
        for(int num : array) {
            if(prev <= num) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 1;
            }
            if(count > maxCount)
                maxCount = count;
            prev = num;
        }
        return maxCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) throws IOException {
        int[] arr = {8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 10, 26, 24};
        System.out.println("Number of repeating positions " + findLongestSorted(arr));
    }
}
```

Note that `prev` is initialized to be the first element in the array since array with only one element is considered to be sorted. After execution of the program, it will print out

```
Number of repeating positions 5
```

If you test on array with only one element, e.g.,

```
int[] arr = {8};
```

It will output:

```
Number of repeating positions 1
```